# How to resolve the error "Property 'dataSource' is required" in springboot

Tags: java

I use two datasource, pg and oracle. When I use javaconfig to create datasource, datasource is null.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DbConfigProperties dbConfigProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean("pgDataSource")
    public DataSource pgDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName(dbConfigProperties.getPgDriverClassName());
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(dbConfigProperties.getPgUsername());
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(dbConfigProperties.getPgPassword());
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(dbConfigProperties.getPgUrl());
        hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(dbConfigProperties.getIdleTimeout());
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(dbConfigProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(dbConfigProperties.getMaximumPoolSize());
        hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(dbConfigProperties.getMinimumIdle());
        return hikariDataSource;
    }
}


@Configuration
public class PgMybatisConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pgDataSource")
    private DataSource pgDataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pgPageInterceptor")
    private PageInterceptor pgPageInterceptor;

    @Bean("pgSqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory pgSqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.zycfc.entity.tag");
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{new ClassPathResource("mapper/tag/*.xml")});
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"));
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setPlugins(new Interceptor[]{pgPageInterceptor});
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(pgDataSource);//here datasource is null
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

Comment: `@Bean("pgDataSource")` shouldn't even compile. Use `@Bean(name = "pgDataSource")`. Also [edit] your question with the error